# How to show the output as a list with only the words in it and not the count?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english')
token = [token for token in token if token not in stopwords_list]
token


freq6000 = []
Wrd_Freq = nltk.FreqDist(token)
Wrd_Freq

df_WrdFreq = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Wrd_Freq, orient='Index') 
df_WrdFreq.columns=['Word Frequency']     


freq6000= df_WrdFreq[(df_WrdFreq('Word Frequency') >= 6000)]
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     13 
     14 
---> 15 freq6000= df_WrdFreq[(df_WrdFreq('Word Frequency') >= 6000)]

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: `df_WrdFreq('Word Frequency')` -> `df_WrdFreq['Word Frequency']`?

Comment: Yes you are correct .. Thank You .. Can you help me to list the output as a list ?